# Hirsch Array Function Returning 0 instead of desired output

Tags: javascript

Trying my hardest to improve but it's been almost 3 hours and I still haven't figured out why this function returns a bunch of 0's

I'm suppose to check the hirsch number of a given array. It is the greatest number n in which n is n times greater than or equal to the values of the array.

This is what I have so far

```js
// Hirsch Number given an array with each space in the array represents a paper and each number represents the amount of citations for a given paper.

function hirschNumber(numberArray)
{
    let hirschIndex = 0;
    let continueCheck = true;
    for (i=0; i < numberArray.length; i++)
    {
        let count = 0;
        let citationsTreshold = hirschIndex + 1
        
        for (i=0; i < numberArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (citationsTreshold <= numberArray[i])
            {
                count++
            }
            if (numberArray.length == (i - 1))
            {
                if (count >= citationsTreshold) 
                {
                    hirschIndex++
                }
                else if (count < citationsTreshold) 
                {
                    continueCheck = false
                    return
                }
            }
            if (continueCheck = false) 
            {
                return hirschIndex
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(hirschIndex)
            }
        }
        if (continueCheck = false) 
        {
            return hirschIndex
        }
        else {
            console.log(hirschIndex)
        };
    };
    return hirschIndex;
};

console.log(hirschNumber([3,0,6,1,5]));
```

Comment: I don't fully follow the intended logic - but it's apparent from your code that you are using the same variable `i` for both loop indices. This is not going to behave well.

Comment: thank you so much, makes sense